# How to prevent deform sides when in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

I am in the process of sculpting some legs from the Y side. (front) But when I look from the side I can see that it is being deformed. is there a method to prevent deformation of the side of the cylinder object. so the sides follow when shaping from the front side? What am I doing wrong?
I use Blender 3.6.2

[image: Front side]

[image: Deformed side]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean but to prevent any deformation you can use the Mask brush, also make sure that the Front Faces Only option of the brush is enabled

Comment: @moonboots I have found out that if I use too many vertices. For example, remesh to 72000 vertices, the object becomes easily deformed and almost impossible to control with 
 the 'Grab' brushs. But if I only remesh the object with 9000 vertices no deformation occurs?

Comment: Mmh it should work with more vertices as well, maybe share your file and explain what you're doing that doesn't work